# remove special symbols and extra spaces and make it camel case javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this function to remove special symbols and extra spaces but to convert thr string to camel case? example

```
kitchener\waterloo to kitchenerWaterloo 

St. Thomas to stThomas

Owen Sound/Walkerton toowenSoundWalkerton
```

javascript code

```
countyName.toLowerCase().replace(/[^A-Z0-9]+/ig,'');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use replace with a function to call uppercase of the letter you want to change.

```
var countyName = "Owen Sound/Walkerton";
var result = countyName
    .trim()  //might need polyfill if you need to support older browsers
    .toLowerCase()  //lower case everything
    .replace(/([^A-Z0-9]+)(.)/ig, //match multiple non-letter/numbers followed by any character
        function(match) { 
            return match[2].toUpperCase();  //3rd index is the character we need to transform uppercase
        }
    );
    console.log(result);
```

Now if the string has a special character up front, this will fail. So the trim method would need to be replaced with

```
.replace(/^[^A-Z0-9]+/gi,"")
```

Answer (score 0):

We can just match what we want by converting negated class to normal character class and then use `Array.map` on 'em.

```
countyName = countyName.toLowerCase().match(/[A-Z0-9]+/ig).map(function(word, i){
    if(!i) return word;
    return word[0].toUpperCase() + word.slice(1); // return newly formed string
}).join("");
```

Comment: @tutankhamun that would join without any spaces.

Comment: I see, but in question:
'St. Thomas to stThomas'

Comment: @solidus.snake check now

Comment: @tutankhamun yup.. you were right. Didn't read the question properly.

Comment: @epascarello no it isn't, going by what camel case means.

Comment: @epascarello and now, I've edited it to suit OP's camel case.